# Bright colors do not display in watch --color

Tags: colors, windows-subsystem-for-linux, watch

Given the following python script to print colored text:

```py
for i in range(30, 100):
    print(f'\033[{i}m{i}\033[0m', end=' ')
print()
```

Running on bash displays bright colors (FG codes 91-97) properly:
[image: bright colors displayed]

However running this code with `watch --color python3 test.py`, the bright colors are not displayed properly:
[image: bright colors not displayed]

Thinking there was a problem with watch commands running in `sh`, I ran with `watch --color --exec bash -c 'python3 test.py'` but with the same result as above.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 via Windows WSL2 but can see similar behavior on RHEL7. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `watch --color` you are asking `watch` to process the ANSI sequences.

The program has a color limit [hardwired into the code](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/v3.3.16/watch.c#L192) and it will *not understand* anything greater than 47. That's for version 3.3.16 (the latest stable). You should be able to check your version with `watch --version`.

```
default:
        if (attrib >= 30 && attrib <= 37) { /* set foreground color */
            fg_col = attrib - 30 + 1;
        } else if (attrib >= 40 && attrib <= 47) { /* set background color */
            bg_col = attrib - 40 + 1;
        } else {
            return 0; /* Not understood */
        }
```

The *master* branch of `watch`[contemplates the bright colors](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/master/watch.c#L267), so eventually it will be fixed and picked up by WSL2. In the meantime your only option is to compile it yourself with that code changed.